# ISA x Desempenho

Tags: desempenho, arquitetura-computadores

De que maneira a quantidade de instruções (ISA) pode afetar a análise de desempenho de um sistema? O compilador pode auxiliar na melhoria dos resultados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISA significa "*Instruction Set Architecture*" - "*Arquitetura de Conjunto de Instruções*". Há dois tipos de arquiteturas a se considerar: RISC e CISC.

O CISC significa "*Complex Instruction Set Computer*" - "*Computador com Conjunto de Instruções Complexo*". Esse tipo de computador apresenta diversos tipos de microinstruções codificados dentro do processador. Por vezes, o número de diferentes tipos de instruções estão nas casas das centenas e frequentemente elas têm formatos e tamanhos bastante variados. Entretanto, devido ao grande número de instruções, o projeto do processador acaba sendo bastante complicado e as instruções podem demorar algum tempo significativo para serem decodificadas e interpretadas, grande parte delas levando diversos ciclos de clock para serem concluídas.

O RISC significa "*Reduced Instruction Set Computer*" - "*Computador com Conjunto de Instruções Reduzido*". Esse tipo de computador apresenta apenas alguns poucos tipos de microinstruções codificados dentro do processador. Por causa disso, essas instruções têm formato e tamanho uniforme, o que também simplifica bastante o projeto do processador e simplifica a decodificação e execução das mesmas. Por vezes, todas ou quase todas elas demoram o mesmo tempo para serem executadas.

Há também uma arquitetura híbrida, que consiste em um processador de duas camadas, sendo a externa CISC e a interna RISC. Nesse processador, cada instrução CISC é traduzida em uma sequência de instruções RISC que são então executadas. Codificada nos circuitos do processador, há uma tabela denominada microcódigo que é utilizada para traduzir cada instrução CISC em uma sequência de instruções RISC.

Outras arquiteturas também são possíveis, especialmente no que concerne a processamento paralelo.

Observe que isso nada diz acerca do desempenho. Ter um grande número de possíveis instruções faz com que cada uma delas possa ser extremamente otimizada em nome de um melhor desempenho, permitindo ao compilador quando for gerar o código, uma ampla gama de possíveis instruções a serem escolhidas e combinadas. Mas isso complica bastante o projeto do processador e pode trazer um custo no desempenho por conta da complexidade. Já com o conjunto de instruções reduzido, um número maior de instruções é necessário ser executado para efetuar algum trabalho útil, mas essas instruções são bastante simples.

Um algoritmo qualquer para realizar alguma tarefa, quando escrito em uma sequência de instruções CISC, costuma ser bem menor do que em uma sequência de instruções RISC. O motivo disso é exatamente porque uma instrução CISC tipicamente representa o trabalho feito por diversas instruções RISC. Mas isso não significa que seja mais rápido e nem que não seja.

Enfim, nenhuma abordagem é inerentemente melhor que a outra. Para entender, imagine o seguinte: João e Maria estão em uma competição para ver quem enche mais rápido uma caixa d'água de 1000 litros. A cada 10 minutos, João despeja um balde que tem em média 20 litros de água (às vezes mais, às vezes menos) na sua caixa. A cada 3 segundos, Maria despeja uma xícara com exatamente 100 ml em sua caixa. Nesse ritmo, ambos demoram 8 horas e 20 minutos para terminar, empatando. Nessa abordagem, cada despejo na caixa d'água corresponde a uma instrução executada e a quantidade de água despejada representa a quantidade de trabalho executada por tal instrução, sendo João o que usa uma abordagem análoga ao CISC e Maria uma análoga ao RISC. Não há uma abordagem claramente melhor em termos de desempenho.

Quanto ao compilador, é ele quem produz a sequência de instruções a ser executada, então ele é que tem a responsabilidade por determinar qual sequência de instruções para realizar a tarefa descrita no programa a ser compilado que resultaria no melhor desempenho. Obviamente, isso não é algo simples, mas significa que o papel dele em melhorar a análise dos resultados é fundamental. Um compilador CISC tem um leque bem maior de possíveis instruções a escolher, o que também significa que é muito mais difícil saber qual seria a melhor combinação possível de sequência de instruções a ser emitida. Já o compilador RISC tem mais uniformidade nas instruções a serem emitidas, o que simplifica a análise, mas provavelmente significa produzir sequências de instruções mais longas.